# Wordpress WP_Query terms with array variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display posts dependant on their tags.

I have some functionality that when I click the term buttons they send off an array of data formatted liked this:

```
array(
   [0] => 'some tag name',
   [1] => 'another tag name'
)
```

In the function below I format that to look something like this:

```
'timbermode','bathroom'
```

I then pass that data into the "terms" section but nothing every gets returned.

```
function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy ) {

    $taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];

    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($taxonomy));

    $stringData = '"' . implode('","', $data) . '"');

   //$stringData = "array('" . implode("','", $data) . "')";

    // WP Query
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'gallery_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'terms'    => array($stringData),
            ),
        )
    );

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  echo "{$query->request}";
}
```

If I manually pass in the terms like so:

```
    // WP Query
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'gallery_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'terms'    => array('some term', 'another term'),
            ),
        )
    );
```

It then works fine. I just can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Codarz

Comment: `$data` is already an array and formated as required. Just set `'terms' => array_values($data)`.

Comment: Absolute legend. 4 and a half hours later it works woohoo! Add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data` is already an array and formated as required. Just set `'terms' => array_values($data)`.